# Databases for Prefix and Reminder Command discord.py

Tags: python, database, sqlite, discord.py

I don't understand much about databases and I want to do one for my reminder command and for my changable prefix. For the prefix I am currently using a json file but someone said it would be better to use database for that. Also my reminder command doesn't store reminders so when the bot is down the reminders are gone. I would be so happy if anyone could help me.

Here is my reminder command's code:

````py
@commands.command(aliases=['remind','remindme'])
    async def reminder(self, ctx, time, *, reminder):
        user = ctx.message.author
        embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.gold())
        seconds = 0
        if reminder is None:
            embed.add_field(name='❌ Wrong Usage', value='`reminder <duration> <reminder>` is the correct way to use this command.')
        if time.lower().endswith("d"):
            seconds += int(time[:-1]) * 60 * 60 * 24
            counter = f"{seconds // 60 // 60 // 24} days"
        if time.lower().endswith("h"):
            seconds += int(time[:-1]) * 60 * 60
            counter = f"{seconds // 60 // 60} hours"
        elif time.lower().endswith("m"):
            seconds += int(time[:-1]) * 60
            counter = f"{seconds // 60} minutes"
        elif time.lower().endswith("s"):
            seconds += int(time[:-1])
            counter = f"{seconds} seconds"
        if seconds == 0:
            embed.add_field(name='❌ Wrong Usage',
                            value='Please specify a proper duration')
        elif seconds > 31536000:
            embed.add_field(name='❌ Wrong Usage', value='You have specified a too long duration!\nMaximum duration is 365 days.')
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"Alright, I will remind you about `{reminder}` in `{counter}`.")
            await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
            await ctx.send(f"**Reminder** {user.mention}: {reminder}")
            return
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have 2 options for databases SQL or NoSQL so MySQL/SQLite/Postgres or MongoDB. You can get a free 500MB MongoDB database from their website but if you are hosting it on a VPS/KVM/dedicated machine/computer you can set both up there. JSON is bad for anything that involves frequent data changes.

Whenever you create a new reminder you must INSERT that into the database. Then you would need to use SELECT/find to get that from it. I have attached an example of using multiple prefixes below with the default prefix being `?` and in DMS if it's in a server/guild it will check the database.

```py
import pymongo
password = os.environ.get("password")
client = pymongo.MongoClient(f"mongodb://127.0.0.1")

def get_prefix(bot, message):
  global client
  if not message.guild:
    return commands.when_mentioned_or("?")(bot, message)
  db = client.bot
  posts = db.serversettings
  prefix = "?"
  for x in posts.find({"guildid":message.guild.id}):
    prefix=x["prefix"]
  return commands.when_mentioned_or(prefix)(bot, message)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix,case_insensitive=True)
```

Comment: Oh perfect! My bot's default prefix is also ?. Thank you

Comment: Hey FluxedScript, can I see a SQL version of this. I might go for SQL.

Comment: @KeroQuero sorry it took me long to reply. If you go into SQL you will need to create your table in advance so that would mean more work for me but you need to have a database, then a table made accepting `guild_id` as varchar 255 or similar with a `prefix` as  TEXT. Then just insert when guild is created or it doesn't exist like on a on_message event. Then just use SELECT to get the prefix. To create a prefix command you will need to use UPDATE